# Calculating the number of injections

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I have the following problem:

> Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and let $R = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$. How
> many injective functions are there from $S$ to $R$?

my answer is that $f(1)$ can take $7$ values, $f(2)$ can take $6$, $f(3)$ can take $5$, $f(4)$ can take $4$, and $f(5)$ can take $3$.

and so $7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3= 2520$ functions.

I would appreciate any feedback/help. thanks.

Comment: Apart from several typos, the math behind this is correct.

Comment: See [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here.  Also note that asterisks `*` are used for writing things `*in italics*` (*in italics*) or `**in bold**` (**in bold**) by enclosing the text between one pair or two pairs of asterisks respectively.  Your attempt to write multiplication with them was rendered incorrectly as a result as the system assumed you wanted to italicize some numbers instead.

Comment: @Torsten Shoeneberg I have made the correction thank you.